# Many-to-Many Dynamic Data DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

[image]

So  I have this table. I have place and users. Users have history of visited places.

Simple question.

How do  I get user data and all up-to-date place data without doing 2 database calls.

In my second item I would need to do duplication of a place, but if I have millions of users who visted a place and that place changes it's name, I would have to update millions of rows...

Any suggestion on how to do that safe data duplication or other strategies for many-to-many dynamic data?